# transparent area that shows part of a picture in css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to create a see through scrolling effect similar to the one on this site http://www.theshawcenter.com/#8987 
I have tried setting the background image and then overlaying white backgrounds, but it is really sloppy and I haven't been able to get it to work right.
What would be the best way to do this?

```
<body class="mainbackground">
<div class="container-fluid">

   <div class="row whiteheader"></div>
        <div class="row hair">
        </div>
   <div class="row white"></div>
</div>
</body>



.mainbackground{
background-image: url(../app/images/background.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
.hair{
opacity:.2;
}

.white{
background-color:white;
height:300px;
}

.whiteheader{
background-color:white;
height:10px;
}
```

This is the latest I have.

Thanks

Comment: Posting what you have tried would be helpful, no matter how sloppy it is...

Answer (score 0):

try using transparent instead except for color white:)

```
    background-color:transparent;
```